# How does the editing of lip-sync take place for non-native artists (especially in songs)?

Tags: film-techniques, editing

I was going through this [answer here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/40887/25800), where @JasonCraig ends the answer with:

> Later a huge portion of issues are sorted in the editing table.

So, I wanted to know **what are the editing methods used to cover-up for the lip-sync of non-native artists?**

He also mentions some techniques used while shooting, which are:

> For lip-sync, actors mumble to themselves, if actors are not native
>   speaker and a close up of actors singing is involved in the worst
>   case, directors ask them to say "abcd" or something close to those
>   lyrics, and will be concealed through camera angles to give viewers an
>   impression that they are indeed singing.

However, he wasn't clear/specific about the techniques. So, **what are the techniques (along with the name if possible) used while shooting for covering up lip-sync of non-native actors?**